# jQuery .text not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I've got a jQuery validation function that adds classes and changes some informational text on blur.  The .addClass and .removeClass methods are working fine but .text does not.  I have a feeling that I'm missing something simple and fundamental but my poor JavaScript knowledge might be a hindrance.  Thanks to anyone who can help!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.required-text').on('blur', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('error');
    if($.trim(this.value).length < 1) {
      $(this).addClass('error');
      var fieldText = "#" + this.id + "_info";
      $(fieldText).removeClass('forminfo');
      $(fieldText).addClass('forminfo_error');
      $(fieldText).text = "This field is required.";
    }
  }
});

<input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" value="" class="form-text required-text">
<span id="first_name_info" class="forminfo">Required</span>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try  `$(fieldText).text("This field is required.");` instead

see documentation about `text()`: http://api.jquery.com/text/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(fieldText).removeClass('forminfo').addClass('forminfo_error').text("This field is required.");
```